# Is there an R function "parallel sum"?

Tags: r

I would like to sum vectors that include NAs.

For example:

```
a <- c(5, 3, 1, NA, 2)
b <- c(NA, 1, 2, 1, 7)
```

The expected output would be:

```
[1] 5 4 3 1 9
```

`sum` doesn't work in this situation, as `sum(a, b, na.rm = T)` is equivalent to `sum(c(a, b), na.rm = T)`.

`+` does work (i.e. `a + b`) but does not remove the `NA`s.

You can use `rowSums(cbind(a, b), na.rm = T)`, but in practice this can lead to messy code - for example if the vectors are columns of a `data.table`.

Is there an equivalent of `pmax` for sum, e.g. `psum(a, b, na.rm = T)`?

Comment: What is your expected output given your input `a` and `b`?

Comment: Just make a copy of a & b and set the NAs to zero in the copy.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the question to show the expected output

Comment: If the vectors are columns of a data.table and you want to do this operation, you might be using the wrong data structure or possibly should reshape that data.table ...

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following using `mapply` to apply the sum function to the two vectors a and b. The `na.rm=TRUE` instructs to remove NA values from the calculation:

```
a <- c(5, 3, 1, NA, 2)
b <- c(NA, 1, 2, 1, 7)

mapply(sum, a, b, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[1] 5 4 3 1 9
```

Or, you can opt to use `reduce` as suggested by @Roland :

```
Reduce("+", lapply(list(a,b), function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))
```

Comment: For longer vectors it would be very inefficient to loop over the vector elements. It would be much faster to write a version of `+` that first turns `NA` values to zero and then use `Reduce` to loop over the vectors.

Comment: Hi @Roland. Thank you for the information. I have added an option to use `Reduce` as well. Also, @DanLewer, if you're interested in learning more about `Reduce`, take a look at [R: Reduce() – apply’s lesser known brother](https://blog.zhaw.ch/datascience/r-reduce-applys-lesser-known-brother/)

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` is what you want:

```r
mapply(sum, a, b, na.rm = TRUE)

# [1] 5 4 3 1 9
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make your own `psum` function

```
psum <- function(x,y){
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
y[is.na(y)] <- 0
x+y
}


> psum(a,b)
[1] 5 4 3 1 9
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar but the function is wrong: its name suggests it does the equivalent to `pmax`, but it doesn’t. It has distinct, and non-generalisable semantics. To be called `psum` it should allow more than two parameters, and also expose an `na.rm` argument with appropriate semantics.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Easy to generalise with `Reduce`.

Comment: @Roland That’s true but that’s not even what I mean (see updated comment).

Comment: @KonradRudolph No problem. Just write a wrapper that uses an `if` condition to use this function or `+` with `Reduce`.

Comment: @Roland I know fixing it is not a problem. I’m pointing out that this answer doesn’t do this, and that this is a problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolph maybe the "p" in my function does not stand for "parallel", but rather "personal". As in, this is my personal function and I can name it whatever I'd like.

Comment: @DanielO In that case it’s still bad naming, and still problematic. 

Comment: @KonradRudolph Those are both a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DanielO No, that’s absolutely not the case. You are falling into the (common) trap of thinking that because something (here, naming) is hard and affected by many factors it’s therefore inherently immune from objective critique. Not so.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are falling into the (common) trap of thinking that your opinion is objective.

Comment: @DanielO No. I think you’re confusing us: I’ve given you objective *arguments* for why the name is bad in my initial comment. Your argument boils down to “I disagree”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214747/discussion-between-daniel-o-and-konrad-rudolph).